# RecyclerLayout inside CoordinatorLayout scrollToPosition visibility

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a using a **CoordinatorLayout** with a **AppBarLayout** inside and an element to try to be able to scroll when RecyclerView is being scrolled. Until that, everything is working as it is suposed to, the problems comes when I try programatically to scrollToPosition of the lasts positions of the **RecyclerView**. The **recyclerViews** does the scroll, but the position I tell to scroll to is not visible (in fact, if I scroll manually, it is visible once the other element inside the **AppBarLayout** has completely scrolled out of the screen). 
**This is my code:**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                    android:id="@+id/chart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="280dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_conso"
                    android:background="@color/background_dark_grey"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_total_conso"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/current_consumption"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@color/graph_consumption_color"
                        android:textSize="30sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/consumption_unit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Smartlink.Large"
                        android:textColor="@color/graph_consumption_color" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the code of the RecyclerView:

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The adapter is a simple text adapter........

When I try to scroll is after receiving an event from a Service, so there is a BroadcastReceiver which receives the event and manage the result:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int position = intent.getExtras().getInt(POSITION);
            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
    }
```

My idea is that I think the **RecyclerView** does't understands that position is not visible.....

Comment: Okay tell me what do you want, recyclerView should not scroll if item is not visible or you want to scroll RecyclerView as well as AppbarLayout?

Comment: What I want is the RecyclerView to scroll to the position I want (and it to be visible for real). If I remove the CoordinatorLayout and the AppBarLayout it is working as I want, the problem is that the RecyclerView scroll to an "invisible" (outside the visibility of the user) position when I do scrollToPosition for the last elements of the list.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code, but this will collapse appbarlayout:

```
  @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
      int position = intent.getExtras().getInt(POSITION);
      app_bar_layout.setExpanded(false);
      recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
  }
```

Comment: I have tried using that, but it is true that that is going to collapse my app_bar_layout.......I dont know if there is any other way to calculate the items which are visible and invisible for real (I tried using the LayoutManager method linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() but the return is an element which is invisible.......)

Comment: The thing you are trying might not be possible because any item of listview or recyclerview is created when it is visible.

Comment: The point is that one, it is not really visible from the point of view of the user cause the AppBarLayout is not collapsed.......Anyway, maybe it is a limitation with the CoordinatorLayout and the AppBarLayout.